# Download binary file with pocolibrary

Tags: c++, poco-libraries

Update:
I fixed it by replacing istream_iterator by istreambuf_iterator.

I try to download binary file using poco.
It seems that it does not correct load file, because content length != actual downloaded length.

```
        Poco::Net::HTTPClientSession session(uri.getHost(), uri.getPort());
        Poco::Net::HTTPRequest request(Poco::Net::HTTPRequest::HTTP_GET, uri.getPathAndQuery(), Poco::Net::HTTPMessage::HTTP_1_1);

        Poco::Net::HTTPResponse response;

        session.sendRequest(request);
        std::istream& rs = session.receiveResponse(response);
        int contentlen = response.getContentLength();

        std::vector<char> bytes;
        std::copy(std::istream_iterator<char>(rs), std::istream_iterator<char>(), std::back_inserter(bytes));
        int byteslen = bytes.size();
```

here contentlen=297008 and byteslen=290420. 
As result, downloaded image is corrupted.
If I download image using curl, it works perfectly, downloaded size = 297008.
What is wrong?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If `libcurl` fits your need, continue using `libcurl` ...!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See the [Poco forum answer](http://pocoproject.org/forum/viewtopic.php?p=11920#p11920).

See also the [download example](https://github.com/pocoproject/poco/blob/develop/Net/samples/download/src/download.cpp):

```
std::auto_ptr<std::istream> pStr(URIStreamOpener::defaultOpener().open(uri));
StreamCopier::copyStream(*pStr.get(), std::cout);
```